# Issue connecting openconnect client tool in dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

I have a dockerfile in which i want to connect openconnect client tool.now when i am trying to build this dockerfile and it is throwing the following error:
Failed to bind local tun device (TUNSETIFF): Operation not permitted
To configure local networking, openconnect must be running as root
See http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/nonroot.html for more information
Set up tun device failed

Answer (score 0):

You need `--cap-add NET_ADMIN` for the container to have enough perms to run `openconnect`.